# Manipulate DOM with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3

Hi guys I'm new at Vue and I want to know how to manipulate the DOM without using stuffs like document.querySelector / getElementbyId etc

For example, if I have an input like this

```html
<input id="myInputId" class="myInputClass" type="text"/>
```

how can I get the id, the class and the type by using Vue tools easily ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ref` for that. I did set up a simple example [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UbtuwzAM/BVCi10gkXfDCVB0CtAunbU4Fp06tR6Q6LRB4H8vZeeFpuggQTzyjkfxJJ69l4cBRSmq2ITOE0Skwa+V7Yx3geAEAdsFOPvmBkuoYYQ2OAMZszJllW2cjQT4XRvf4zu2sEqM3A59/5TyV2aeP8FqDScG6VYuD3U/4Hwz9SHR6T/rm76O8bWLJGut84ww0kuCMu458qmKeRwehANCZteEHAFUnfUDpRckpyslbupKzHinGTbHTarc6As6Nb0lpoaXHB09coqd0gwV3Kwq7jpzGOnYI8TGedSTF3k1Pv+Lom3dfO4C/5gu2R0PDzBO4yTqWizEvJelqb3cR2d5c8wEUOcEGyqTVvKkBC8pxUp8EPlYFkVsm7TvfZQu7Ap+ycDL6QxKjGa5De4rYmBhJRZ3GgWDBwzLgFZjwPCf5q/SB93zRKMYfwCpi+Bu), using Vue3 + composition API. You now can do whatever you want with it.

Vue docs - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html